# icudt error while installing stringi library in R

Tags: r, icu, stringi

I'm writing this because it took me several days to come to this result.

Bottom line:  The stringi library version 1.1.3 (released March 2017) might have issues involving icudt.  You can install stringi 1.1.2 using the following commands:

```
packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/stringi/stringi_1.1.2.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

I put this together from some RStudio documentation on [how to install an older package](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages).

Background:

I was trying to install the forecast library in R. Originally, I was using R 3.1.2.  I also installed R 3.3.3 and tried to install stringi it.  I'm running CentOS 6.7 and don't have a choice to upgrade.

Forecast failed to install due to issues installing stringi.  The stringi library failed to install due to errors downloading ICU data library (icudt)
It looks like stringi 1.1.3 added download/build logic regarding icudt, and upcoming version 1.1.4 has corrections to this logic (as of date 2017-04-02).

I went to the ICU project site: and downloaded/installed the ICU library that appeared to be specified in the error messages below:

```
checking whether we may compile src/icu55/common/umapfile.c... yes
checking whether we may compile src/icu55/common/putil.cpp... yes
checking whether we can fetch icudt... WARNING: ignoring environment value of R_HOME
downloading ICU data library (icudt)
output path: icu55/data/icudt55l.zip
Error in stri_download_icudt("icu55/data") :
  could not find function "dir.exists"
Calls: identical -> stri_download_icudt
Execution halted
*** icudt could not be downloaded. stopping.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘stringi’
```

Searches online for icu55, icudt55l.zip, or any procedure that followed to get past this error didn't turn up a procedure that worked.  I downloaded, built, and installed ICU 55.1 and also ICU 58.2.  I also updated gcc and g++.  The CRAN repository install notes for stringi 1.1.3 don't currently give a straightforward set of instructions to successfully install stringi when I have a working internet connection.

I started by asking this as a question and then found my answer.  I'll post it anyways. I had added several links but needed to remove them because I don't have enough cred to get away with them.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with ICU. This is a bug in stringi, which I have already fixed in version 1.1.5 (now on CRAN). The `dir.exists()` function is specific to  R ≥ 3.2.0 - I wasn't aware of that.  Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: I'm trying to install 1.1.5 on RHEL unfortunately it isn't working because R can't find the right version of ICU4C and obviously tries to compile something but can't download icudt (behind firewall).  What do you suggest?  Where can I dowonload icudt and put it in the right place? Thanks...

Comment: @Dieter.Wilhelm The INSTALL documentation for stringi states: **If you decide to use our ICU4C bundle then, by default, the ICU data library
will be downloaded from one of our mirror servers. However, if you have already
downloaded a version of icudt*.zip suitable for your platform
(big/little endian), you may wish to install the package by calling:**

    `install.packages("stringi", configure.vars="ICUDT_DIR=<icudt_dir>")`  You can then put the already downloaded zip wherever you'd like and refer to it in <icudt_dir>

Answer (score 1):

The stringi library version 1.1.3 (released March 2017) might have issues involving icudt. You can install stringi 1.1.2 using the following commands:

```
packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/stringi/stringi_1.1.2.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```